# Is it possible to use a variable (json key) to another variable (json value) in Airflow Variables?

Tags: json, variables, airflow

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Apache Airflow and I'm keen to know if there's a way to use a variable (json key) to another variable (json value) in Airflow Variables? Is there a straightforward approach aside from doing a string replace beforehand on the json file? Thanks and appreciate any help and advice!

```
{
  "my_variables":
   {
    "s3_bucket": "s3://my_prod_bucket",
    "dateset_1": s3_bucket + "/dataset_1_path/",
    "dataset_2": s3_bucket + "/dataset_2_path/",
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature currently. My recommendation will be to write a small util to do it, and possibly you could even contribute it to Apache Airflow.